# Pros and Cons of implementing Properties in Java

Tags: c#, java, properties, theory

In C# there exists a type of member that is called a Property. This allows you to easily and simply define a private field and provide simple or complex getters and setters while saving space by not having to define whole methods. Java does not have anything like this, and from what I can see, the general consensus has been to suck it up and define complete getter and setter methods for private variables.

Currently, I have been toying with the following class:

```
public class Property<T> {

    private T value = null;

    public Property(){}
    public Property(T initialValue){
        value = initialValue;
    }

    public T get(){
        return value;
    }

    public void set(T newValue){
        value = newValue;
    }

}
```

With this implementation, you can define simple properties that only require getters and setters:
`final Property<String> name = new Property<>("Dog");`

Or more advanced options [like the one that MSDN provides for C#:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

```
...
public double seconds;

public final Property<Double> Hours = new Property<Double>(){
    @Override
    public Double get() {
        return seconds/3600;
    }

    @Override                                              
    public void set(Double newValue) {
        seconds = newValue * 3600;
    }
};
...
```

What would be the pros and cons of this solution?

Answer (score 2):

The pros are largely obvious. I'll point out some that make it better than C#'s properties:

1. The backing field is tucked away so that you don't accidentally use it instead of the property. (but the downside is that you can't easily choose to use the backing field if you want)
2. Unlike C#'s auto-properties, you can choose to override only the `get` or `set` method, not both, e.g.

   ```
   public Property<List<String>> MyList = new Property<List<String>>(){
       @Override
       public List<String> get() {
           if (value == null)
               value = new ArrayList<String>();
           return value;
       }
       // set still works
   };
   ```

There are cons, however:

1. It is not part of the Java language, or any common libraries, so it can be confusing for people who read your code (including yourself in the future).
2. You cannot change the visibility of the `get` and `set` methods: if the `Property<T>` can be accessed, you can both get and set the value.
3. If you don't make your `Property` field `final`, anyone that can access it can change it to their own `Property` implementation. This could be useful, but mostly would be a pain.
4. (this is a con shared with C#'s properties) You can't change the arguments that are passed to the `get` and `set` methods. E.g. you can't have a `Property<MyType>` with both a `set(MyType)` and a `set(CompatibleType)` method (unless you extend `Property`).
5. Using generics pervasively means that at run-time, (thanks to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)) you're using `Object` pervasively. This boxing/unboxing might make for a slight performance decrease (not noticeable in most apps) if you use primitives (e.g. using `double` vs `Property<Double>`).

By the way, [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) is a language that runs on the JVM that includes properties as a native feature, and interoperates with Java's version of properties (getters/setters). You might want to look into that, since basically someone else already hacked the Java language for you. =)

All in all, I'd say you shouldn't try to make Java have properties. When in Rome, do as the Romans do. If you don't like how the Romans do it, move down the street (Scala) or across the country (C#).

Comment: Good explanation, I would give you another for mentioning *Scala* if I could

Comment: @omainegra - I just did give him another (+1) for mentioning Scala.

Answer (score 1):

So the complete syntax, say for name, would now be:

```
theObject.name.set("new name");
```

The point is, how are you accessing that name object? Is it public / protected Then it could be overridden. Is it private? Then you can't change it outside the class anyways.

The solution you've proposed only works if you already have access to the object, at which point you don't need the solution.

Comment: According to his example it will be `object.Hours.set(3600.0)`, and it is find, but I don't see the advantage yet.

Answer (score 0):

**The pros** of this solution (your anonymous inner class) is that, if you are not needing to implement this anywhere else, it saves you from writing an entire extra class just for this one situation.

**The con** of this solution is that later you may want to implement it elsewhere, and then you'd want to refactor your code to extract the implementation of Property<Double> into its own class to avoid repeating yourself.

**I'd say**, if you're pretty sure you're not going to need this implementation anywhere else (I'm guessing you won't), just go ahead with the later solution of an anonymous inner class.  It's a good one.